# how do i build coreclr applications with dnx

Tags: macos, asp.net-core, dnx, dnvm, coreclr

i have installed dnvm, coreclr, as instructed on my mac:

http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-mac.html

and if i call list

```
peteisace$:    dnvm list

Active Version              Runtime Arch OperatingSystem Alias
------ -------              ------- ---- --------------- -----
       1.0.0-beta6          mono         linux/darwin    
   *   1.0.0-beta7-12302    coreclr x64  darwin          
       1.0.0-beta7-12302    mono         linux/darwin    default
```

so it would seem dnxcore50 is installed...

however if i try to restore, build, run, nothing happens when on coreclr; it just the same as hit enter. no attempt to do anything:

```
peteisace$    dnu restore
peteisace$
```

same if i try to build / run / whatever command there is:

```
peteisace$    dnx . run
peteisace$
```

and so if i try to build my application using mono:

```
 peteisace$    dnvm use 1.0.0-beta7-12302 -r mono
 peteisace$    System.InvalidOperationException: The current runtime target framework is not compatible with 'sampleConsole'.

Current runtime target framework: 'DNX,Version=v4.5.1 (dnx451)'
 Version:      1.0.0-beta7-12302
 Type:         Mono
 Architecture: x64
 OS Name:      Darwin
```

any suggestions would be welcome. i don't know how to validate the coreclr is installed properly. the runtime directory is populated:

```
$peteisace ls -l ~/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-coreclr-darwin-x64.1.0.0-beta7-12302/
/Users/peteisace/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-coreclr-darwin-x64.1.0.0-beta7-12302/:
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  108 peteisace  peteisace  3672 Aug  4 09:29 bin
-rw-r--r--    1 peteisace  peteisace   725 Aug  4 09:55 dnx-coreclr-darwin-x64.nuspec
drwxr-xr-x    3 peteisace  peteisace   102 Aug  4 09:29 package
```

Comment: Same exact scenario.  I'm using the example code from http://dotnet.github.io/core/getting-started/.  If I do dnx . run when pointed at mono, it executes, no need to build first, but like you, no response when pointed at coreclr.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the right commands. dnx on Darwin/Linux CoreCLR is still very broken.

When you encounter bugs using the latest dnx builds, you may have more luck reaching out to the dnx team by filing an issue on their GitHub repo.

[DNX on GitHub](http://github.com/aspnet/dnx)

Answer (score 0):

DNX on CoreCLR is supposed to be much better beginning in beta7.  The question was from August and beta 7 was released around the first of September.  Could you try the instructions at that same link now?